# How do you stop the rendering of the website to have something display on the front-end?

Tags: loop, theme-customizer

I'm currently trying to insert a page on my logged-in homepage, as follows:

`header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ABSPATH = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
    </script>
</head>
<?php 
$setup_screen = new Landing; 
$setup_screen->render_screen();
?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <header id="masthead" class="header">
```

The class renders a screen on my homepage. Unfortunately, at this point in time, it's not needed for WordPress to do anything, nor should it.

Adding an `if` on the header or completely removing the contents of the header doesn't do it, as sidebars / footers still get loaded.

How can I approach this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the header rather than your front page template?

Comment: @Milo I am not. or I am. No idea, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the header and footer same for logged in and non-logged in users, you can add your IF condition in the file generating your front page (ex. front-page.php or index.php). This is completely dependent upon the theme you are using.

For example in the WP's default twentyseventeen theme, the front-page.php file calls the template file content-front-page.php to generate content on the homepage. You can create your own template file and call it here using a conditional statement.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'front-page-loggedin' );
}
else {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'front-page' );
}
```

This will make WP load your custom template file when visitors are logged in users. I found [this](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/) article that will help you in creating a custom template file.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Works!

Guess I have to query the scripts in-line now, the CSS and so on.